# Error on migrating from EF Core 5 to EF Core 6

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-core-5.0, ef-core-6.0

I have a problem with my db model after migrating from EF Core 5 to EF Core 6.
On context creation I get error: the given key was not present in the dictionary.
Example app repo: https://github.com/testApp6/TestApp
Any ideas whats wrong or how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a bug.  So it should be raised as an issue [here](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues).

The reflection code to process your attributes is getting confused by your explicit interface implementation:

```
[ForeignKey(nameof(PostTypeEnum))]
[InverseProperty(nameof(Model.PostType.Posts))]
public PostType PostType { get; set; }

[NotMapped]
PostTypeCommon IPost.PostType => PostTypeEnum.ToCommon();
```

To work around just delete the attribute from Post:

```
[Table(nameof(PostType))]
public class PostType
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public virtual PostTypeEnum Enum { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(20), Required]
    public virtual string Code { get; set; }

    //[InverseProperty(nameof(Post.PostType))]
    public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}
```

You're already configuring the InverseProperty on the other side of the Navigation Property *and* in OnModelCreating.  So no need for it here too.

Comment: Thanks for help :) Bug reported.